# server side scripts run as root or a viable interactive way in php

Tags: php, bash, scripting, server-side, administration

i'm trying to find out the way to perform administrativa tasks in a local server as different scripts most of them having actions that require root permissions.

How can i execute these scripts with the least security impact?¿

I send some example scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == '-h' ];
then
  echo +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
  echo +                               Instrucciones                           +
  echo +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
  echo Para ejecutar el script hay que hacer cd hasta /var/www/scripts/server .. 
  echo ejecutar ----> bash crearhosts $dominio $dominio $dominio $status
  echo Se pueden poner tantos dominios como se quiera sin extensión salvo el último parámetro que ha de ser el tipo de site con los siguientes valores validos:
  echo localzone1
  echo localzone2
  echo localzone3
  echo +------------ejemplo-------------+
  echo bash domain domain domain localzone
  echo +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
  echo +                               fin                                     +
  echo +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
else 

    #+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    #+                               Variables                               +
    #+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

    params=$*
    array=$(echo $params | sed 's/ /;/g')
    IFS=";"
    set -- $array
    sites=($array)

    base="/var/www"
    #+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    #+                               funciones                               +
    #+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    function hostconf(){
      case $status in
        aracne)
          cp /var/www/vhosts/template.ethings.com.conf /var/www/vhosts/$domain-aracne.ethings.com.conf  
          grep -Rl -e 'ethings/template' /var/www/vhosts/$domain-aracne.ethings.com.conf | xargs sed -i 's:domain/template:domain/'$domain'-aracne:g'
              grep -Rl -e 'template' /var/www/vhosts/$domain-domain.com.conf | xargs sed -i 's/template/'$domain'-aracne/g' 
          mkdir $base/$status/${directorios[0]}-aracne ; mkdir $base/$status/${directorios[0]}-dominio/${directorios[1]} ; mkdir $base/$status/${directorios[0]}-dominio/${directorios[2]}
              echo +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
              echo "+----------------------No OLVIDE AÑADIR EL DOMINIO "$domain"-domain.com para la ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx en su archivo hosts"
              echo +----------------------------------------------------------------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!---------------------------------------------------------+;;

        static)
          cp /var/www/vhosts/template.ethings.com.conf /var/www/vhosts/$domain.ethings.static.com.conf  
          grep -Rl -e 'ethings/template' /var/www/vhosts/$domain.ethings.static.com.conf | xargs sed -i 's:ethings/template:ethings/static-webs/'$domain':g'
          grep -Rl -e 'template.ethings' /var/www/vhosts/$domain.ethings.static.com.conf | xargs sed -i 's/template.ethings/'$domain'.ethings.static/g'
          mkdir $base/ethings/$status-webs/${directorios[0]}; mkdir $base/ethings/$status-webs/${directorios[0]}/${directorios[1]}; mkdir $base/ethings/$status-webs/${directorios[0]}/${directorios[2]}
              echo +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
              echo "+----------------------No OLVIDE AÑADIR EL DOMINIO "$domain".domain.com para la ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx en su archivo hosts"
              echo +----------------------------------------------------------------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!---------------------------------------------------------+;;
        *)
          cp /var/www/vhosts/template.domain.com.conf /var/www/vhosts/$domain.ethings.com.conf  
          grep -Rl -e 'template' /var/www/vhosts/$domain.domain.com.conf | xargs sed -i 's/template/'$domain'/g'
          mkdir $base/ethings/${directorios[0]} ; mkdir $base/ethings/${directorios[0]}/${directorios[1]} ; mkdir $base/ethings/${directorios[0]}/${directorios[2]}
              echo +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
              echo "No OLVIDE AÑADIR EL DOMINIO "$domain".domain.com para la ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx en su archivo hosts"
              echo +-----------------------------------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!------------------------------------------+;;
      esac
    }

    #echo ${#sites[@]} +-------+ elements of array  +--------+
    for((count=0; count<$((${#sites[@]}-1)); count++))
    do
      directorios=("${sites[$count]}" "html" "logs")
      domain=${sites[$count]}
      status=${sites[$((${#sites[@]}-1))]}
      hostconf $status
    done
        /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
fi
```

#

As you can see this script must be run as root for it has many actions that require so

Another scriptt:

```
echo password | python /var/www/google_appengine/appcfg.py --passin --email=email update localapplicationurl
```

#

when i run it i get apache errors with permissions for appcfg.py even chmoding 4755 and visudoing to all all=nopasswd: urlscript/script

And other tries.

Sorry to post so many questions but i really need to be able to run many scripts so that people in my company can do it as web interface.

---

Thank you for your answer. Well is basically a plesk type panel personalized to my own needs. That includes creating samba configurations, vhost configurations, upload websites to remote servers and so download them, automating installation of databases on programmers needs, creating users groups, etc is a company with over 1000 domains i set four local servers for production we have scripts for uploading to cdn in google and amazon, etc. I have all this set up in independent scripts but need to somehow be able to get people do this in website interface. It would release a lot of work from me (i'm the only one doing this) and be able to concentrate on webservers optimizaton and others. So i need to do this and most scripts involve ssh conections over ssh to at least 30 different servers or downloading-uploading 100 minisites at once (ssh connections ftp etc), or running google cdn with python and sdk and else and else. Most of this having to be on behalf of users need that is get these domains from this server - give option to select them - select action - run upload-download-cleanremotecache-erasespecificfilesfolders-etc script.

That is the thing. The good thing about this is i can block total access to the server by iptables or by local specific mac addresses in servers confs, and so. It needs to only run in local and be able to run sripts that involve mostly root commands.

I just need to focus on best way to do it most things found in google don't work as spected, or similar. When i get the way of approach the rest is a matter of putting hands to it.

Sorry to extend myself so much but as you see i have a lot of things to do and my experience in computers and linux started a year ago.

Comment: [How do i format my code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Running anything as root (server, script, etc.) leaves major security holes. Do you simply need root access to install the scripts? If that's the case, login as root, and install them to their perspective directories. If it is some sort of web interface (similar to like cPanel or other), install the script as root, but have your web interface run on its own user which then just copies the data to the users' accounts (give the user write permissions to the '/home' directory).

Comment: There's no need to close and reopen quotes in an `echo`. Rather than `echo "---"$var"---"`, just do `echo "---$var---"`. Your "Variables" block seems to be doing several things unnecessarily. You make use of your `$base` variable in some places, but it could be used in several more. It's not necessary to use `$(())` inside a `for (())` - you can do the math directly. The same thing is true inside an array subscript - instead of `[$((a-b))]` just do `[a-b]`.

Comment: You might consider setting some variables in your `case` statement and performing the actions afterwards. This could abstract the actions and you wouldn't have to have so much repetitive code.

Comment: thx for tips on code i just tumble into code as i go along with things not working as they should. But maybe it is just because of path trying at first to run it as sh script and then bash script, which makes a big diffrence sometimes.

Comment: As for what i really need is some sort of plesk interface running these scripts through php and parameter set by web user. Raged i do everythings as root scripts are created as root i just need to launch then as web user in some sort of cpanel style and when i run some of them start working but fail in anything having to do with root permissions as apache restart or trying to run a google application script from google by python apache sends me back permission problems. I wonder if there is a way to bypass this. I mean i can run the script but folder creation program executions fail.

Comment: sorry to write so much, but i need this to be done somehow to unload my duties at the company and allow partners to generate upload download sites in our local servers and remote ones. This necessity comes because we have over 1000 domains to administer and 30 remote servers and 4 local ones. So if someone needs to start working locally i don't need to create hosts conf folders etc so is for uploading and downling and many other scripts i have to update data at mysql for each domain etc etc etc. So the most i can unload for me the less crappy scripts i will do o_=.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the real question here is if you really need to run those scripts as root from a web interface, that's extremely unsafe and not recommended.

You should log to the server and install them manually, then leave the web interface to install anything else that does not requires root access.

Anyway I think you can look for some time of solution to this over google, but it's not recommended and violates the general permissions design of linux.

Comment: Hi there thx for answers, i have been googling quite a lot and tried different solutions as sudoing scripts passing root user and password and others. The thing is that our local servers do not have access from internet is a mirror of our online sites against which we eork. I must have a database updated and runtime configurations for samba apache etc... up to date regarding over 700 domains. I have scripts that go thru every single domain getting actual ip if is online has drupal wordpress and so on.. Also i need to somehow get to configure local domains automatically within...

Comment: a friendly interface for non technical users (content people), and most scripts end up having to restart apache or run python for automathic google cdn upload and amazon updates, etc. So far i must do it on request and i run those scripts withe the domains desired, but it would be awesome to do it as web interface so that anyone could do it. So far my solution is setting up a nginx for the admin site on different port and running as root, but i just want to have hints on what other alternate methods i might have. The problem always is  that every person has a different method and not all work.

Comment: I understand your idea, but always the root access is the worst solution. You can create a user to which you will grant permission to do everything you need, also restart services or execute python scripts. The best option I can think now is to create some app that offer to you a WebService, which will be hearing for commands from your web interface and that user (which is running the WebService) is the one that will do anything you want. Anyway, it's difficult to think about a solution without know exactly what you have to work. Hope it helps!